# How to return an empty model if Gson error occures

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I use Retrofit+Gson in my Android app.
Sometimes I get such exception:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
>   retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert

I don't want my app to be crashed when server responds bad requests.

Is there a way to return an empty ResponseBody (Model) if such error occures?

```
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder()
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addInterceptor(TokenInterceptor(preferencesHelper))
            .addInterceptor(ClientInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(mHttpLoggingInterceptor)
            .build()

 val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(...)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
            .create(...)
```

Comment: No, better way is to surround your code with **try/catch block** and do stuff inside catch block when exception occurs.

Comment: Is it possible to resolve it by using `okHttp Interceptor` for common response/response error handlers?